# Registration Form Debug & Post Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**So I'm going to try and explain this to the best of my ability.** I am taking a Rails tutorial and am a little stuck on the POST and Debug sections.

**1st Question:** I created a registration form. The tutorial said to click the "Register!" button to see what happens. Apparently nothing is supposed to happen except when I click the "Register!" button I get an error `No route matches [POST] "/register"`. How do  I fix that?

**2nd Question:**
We then added a debug function in the `application.html.erb` section which looks like this:

```
<% if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'development' %>
        <%= debug(params) %>
    <% end %>
```

They said to try and create a user with the username: foo password: baz email: bar and see what happens. Apparently when I click register it's supposed to not change the page but just show some stuff in the debug function?

[image]

My debug function shows this until I click the register button and then it gives me the error `No route matches [POST] "/register"`.

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
controller: users
action: register
```

when in the book it shows that you don't get the error `No route matches [POST] "/register"` but instead you get this text in your debug function...

```
--- !ruby/hash:HashWithIndifferentAccess
user: !ruby/hash:HashWithIndifferentAccess
screen_name: foo
password: baz
email: bar
commit: Register!
action: register
controller: users
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Just incase you want to know some of my code here it is:

**Routes.rb**

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get '/users', to: 'users#index'

      get 'register', to: 'users#register'

      get '/site', to: 'site#index'

      get '/about', to: 'site#about'

      get '/help', to: 'site#help'

      resources :users, only: %w(index) do
        get :register, on: :collection
      end

      root 'site#index'
```

**Users.controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def register
    @title = 'Register'
    if request.post? and params[:user]
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        render :text => 'Welcome to WorkLink!'
      # Output goes to log file (log/development.login development mode)
      logger.info params[:user].inspect
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did wrong with routing. You declare get method for register. But it should be post method.

You have to change your route to

```
post 'register', to: 'users#register'
```